# How to generate a uniformly random number U(-1,1) in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to generate a uniformly distributed random number from -1 to 1 using C#, which is U(-1,1) in math sign. The expected result should be a real number.

Comment: Define "number" more specifically.

Comment: Is the expected result an integer or a real number?

Comment: I'm guessing they're after a scalar so -1.0 -> 1.0

Comment: Yeah it would make sense, but someone might want to obtain either -1, 0 or 1 randomly as well. I'm not familiar with the `U(-1,1)` notation though...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

User Random.NextDouble() and multiply the result by 2 then subtract 1.

The code:

```
var rand = new Random();
var value = rand.NextDouble() * 2 - 1;
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason for the var as opposed to Double?

Comment: @davbryn you can search SO for *"when to use `var` and when to use `realtype`"*. I see no problem here.

Comment: `NextDouble`'s return value are in the range `[0.0, 1.0)` so obtaining the value `1.0` (as asked by OP) is impossible.

Comment: @davbryn Less to write ... it is not very useful here, but imagine the type returned by List<Dictionary<int,string>>.GetEnumerator() for example :)

Comment: _Actually_, I like this answer. But I'm not sure it is fit for _uniformly distributed_ term. Also I think OP doesn't want `-1` or `1` as a result since it's using `()` instead of `[]`

Comment: @Vache and what is wrong with it. Question is `U(-1,1)` not `U[-1,1]` . So what you only need is to exclude the `exact -1`.

Comment: @L.B I thought that the `U( ... )` was different than normal range notation and "from -1 to 1" led me to believe that he wanted the extreme values. Then again shouldn't -1 be excluded as well then? `NextDouble` can return `0.0`.

Comment: @SonerGönül From MSDN `Pseudo-random numbers are chosen with equal probability from a finite set of numbers.` I think it fit to the requirement.

Comment: I am not good at math notation, but excluding -1 is easy, adding 1 and keeping uniformity a little harder.

Comment: @L.B It wasn't edited as I was writing. Do you have a link that explains this `U` notation? I've been through physics and computer science studies without ever meeting it...

Comment: @Vache a) Yes it was. b) and you can use your intiution for it if you have enough background as you say.

Comment: @L.B Well visibly my intuition was wrong since I guessed it was a uniform distribution between the specified limits. This isn't a pissing contest, I'm not saying the answer is wrong since you showed me it was right, I'm just trying to learn.

Comment: @L.B I didn't imply a problem; I've never enjoyed C# so wondered if there was a decent reason: "lack of keystrokes" seems to be a problem though. IMHO skipping type declaration because of extremely ugly syntax is the problem. But each to their own - var away :-D

Comment: @davbryn It is not because ugly syntax, it is because it is faster to write.

Comment: @Bogdan  List<Dictionary<int,string>>.GetEnumerator() is pretty?

Comment: @davbryn That was an example, the actual code will be cleaner. (I do not know how to write code in comments).

Comment: @davbryn what do you want to say?  this topic is discussed millions of times and C# community (I hope) knows when to use it. If you are really curious about it, ask to a related forum.

Comment: @davbryn New to stack overflow and I have trouble with using comments, I was replying to your comment and not commenting on my answer.

Comment: @L.B Entirely the point: Comments sections are not for questions, but for discussion. You jump in telling me to search for an answer for a question I didn't ask you for; As an aside, if it has been asked a million times before, surely the consensus many people hold  is that it is a flaw?

Comment: @Bogdan don't sweat it :) I up voted your answer if it helps, and only reared my ugly head after an innocent question got jumped on by a random

Comment: @davbryn Thanks. Related to var - I started using it because for me the keystrokes matter since I like to write fast, but I think it is a matter of preference after all. Also it helps a little with readability.

Answer (score 0):

As an extension method:

```
public static double NextDoubleBetween(this Random r, double lower, double upper)
{
    return r.NextDouble() * Math.Abs(upper - lower) + lower;
}
```

Use:

```
Random r = new Random();
Console.WriteLine(r.NextDoubleBetween(-1, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

True uniformity for random numbers is currently only guaranteed in a strong way (with theoremic proof) for the special case of cryptography.

The `Random` class presents some non-uniform and even predictable behavior, while the strong (and expensive) implementation is far more reliable on unpredictablility.

You can find the class here: [RandomNumberGenerator crypto service provider implementation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Quick information about RNG: [RNG on DotNet Perls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/rngcryptoserviceprovider)

Note *there* (on DotNet Perls) the cost of creating the numbers between Random and RandomNumberGenerator: 2796 ns versus 9 ns... that tells you how much that is expensive and also how much care was taken for this very strong implementation.

To have a number between -1 and 1 you'll have to do some legwork, because you only get raw bytes from the *RNG*, but this should help you pretty well along:

[BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You should fill an array with bytes from the *RNG* and then use `BitConverter.ToDouble()` to retain as much entropy as possible:

```
using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    byte[] buffer64bit = new byte[4];

    rng.GetBytes(buffer64bit);
    double value = BitConverter.ToDouble(buffer64bit, 0);
}
```

You'll have now to cap it from -1 to +1, as the `value` will range from `double.MinValue` to `double.MaxValue`. You can achieve this by using a modulo 2 and then subtracting 1:

```
value = (value % 2) - 1;
```

This will now be a random double from -1 to +1 with as much uniformity as is currently possible in C#. To go beyond you would need a specialized implementation that hooks into the *RNG* (this is used with hardware generators that use thermic sensors for *extremely* strong cryptographic implementations).

Answer (score 0):

pid answer has a small bug. The allocated buffer is of 32 bits instead of 64. So change:

```
byte[] buffer64bit = new byte[4];
```

To:

```
byte[] buffer64bit = new byte[8];
```